# Как динамически получить сообщение из messages при помощи thymeleaf?

Tags: java, jquery, spring, thymeleaf, i18n

При помощи ajax запроса я получаю некоторые данные.

```
        $("#currencyDeleteSubmit").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: 'rest/currency/delete/' + $('#currencySelect').val(),
            type: 'GET',
            success: function(result) {
                window.location.replace("/main");
            },
            error: function (result) {
                $('#deleteCurrencyModal').modal('toggle');
                $("#currencyMessageAlert").show();
                $("#currencyMessage").html(result.responseJSON.message);
            }
        });
    });
```

**result.responseJSON.message** хранит в себе код, при помощи которого я хочу получить сообщение из **ResoureceBundle**. 
Я пытался подсунуть этот код в обработчик thymeleaf, но к сожалению из этого ничего не вышло, т.к. thymleaf работает на серверной части и динамически подставить туда код не получится.
Подскажите как выйти из данной ситуации? Проблема заключается в том, что **ResoureceBundle** содержит несколько языков.
Пробовал обрабатывать сообщение прямо на сервере, но не могу понять как получить **Local** из контекста, без добавления в запрос.

```
@Component
public class Messages {

    @Autowired
    private MessageSource messageSource;

    private MessageSourceAccessor accessor;

    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        accessor = new MessageSourceAccessor(messageSource, LocaleContextHolder.getLocale());
    }

    public String get(String code) {
        return accessor.getMessage(code);
    }

}
```

Comment: тебе нужен класс с аннотацией @RestController, который обработает GET запрос rest/currency/delete/:currency